# Ring Isomorphism Proof

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime with $p \equiv 1 (\mod 4 )$.

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 1, p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a ring isomorphism.

I am not really sure how to approach the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to write an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: Hint: When $p\equiv 1\pmod4$, there are two roots of $f(X)=X^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: When you see the ideal $(X^2+1,p)$ you should think of it as a kernel of a (surjective) homomorphism (have the first isomorphism theorem in mind)
$$f: \mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/p$$

Clearly, $f$ is sending a polynomial with integer coefficients $g(X)$ to an element $(c,d)$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/p.$ This should be the reminiscent of evaluation at some elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ (*i.e.* you should do something to $g(X)$ to get a number in $\mathbb{Z}/p$) and you should define $f$ in a way that $X^2+1$ and $p$ both get mapped to $(0,0).$ As said, $X^2+1$ has two roots over $\mathbb{Z}/p.$

Can you conclude from here?